# How to check for a range of values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in which I want to check if a future value is greater than the given value for a range of future dates.
For example

```
np.where((df['Close'].shift(-1) - df['Close'])  > 0 , 1, 0)
```

This will give me if next value is greater than current value, I want to check if current value is greater than say next 5 values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.rolling_max` for this, something like

```
window = 5
pd.rolling_max(df['Close'], window).shift(-window) - df['Close'])  > 0
```